# Build OpenCV with CUDA support

Tags: opencv, cuda

Im use CMake to generate visual studio 2013 solution. Next im try to build it, but get follow error:

> Building NVCC (Device) object modules/core/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/src/cuda/Debug/cuda_compile_generated_gpu_mat.cu.obj
>
> nvcc fatal   : Unsupported gpu architecture 'compute_11'

Im try version 2.10 and 3.0 with cuda 6.5 and 7.0.
CUDA_ARCH_BIN set to : 1.1 1.2 1.3 2.0 2.1(2.0) 3.0 3.5

Answer (score 23):

Another option.
Ubuntu 14.04, GTX Titan X, opencv-2.4.10

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D BUILD_TIFF=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D CUDA_GENERATION=Auto -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON  ..
```

I also applied the [patch](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/pull/3886/files),
but I'm not sure whether it ended up being needed.  I had tried with and without`CUDA_GENERATION=Maxwell` but Maxwell isn't detected. I did not try `CUDA_GENERATION=Auto` prior to the patch, that's why I don't know for sure.

Comment: why build tiff?

Comment: @user136266 because some of the processing I do is with tiffs. They're common for geospatial data, rasters and such.

Answer (score 13):

When using cmake to do configurations,  set the option **CUDA_GENERATION** to specific your GPU architecture. I ran across the same error and tried this to work out the problem.

Answer (score 11):

Following up on Yun's answer (could not leave comment), this worked for me and shows a possible value for **CUDA_GENERATION**:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D CUDA_GENERATION=Kepler ..
```

(Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04, GTX Titan, and OpenCV 2.4.11 and 3.0.0.)

Answer (score 7):

You can use `CUDA_GENERATION` to specify the corresponding generation code name for your GPU architecture.

Here's the relevant [opencv cmake code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/cmake/OpenCVDetectCUDA.cmake#L64-L86) that parses the `CUDA_GENERATION` value:

```c
  set(__cuda_arch_ptx "")
  if(CUDA_GENERATION STREQUAL "Fermi")
    set(__cuda_arch_bin "2.0")
  elseif(CUDA_GENERATION STREQUAL "Kepler")
    set(__cuda_arch_bin "3.0 3.5 3.7")
  elseif(CUDA_GENERATION STREQUAL "Maxwell")
    set(__cuda_arch_bin "5.0 5.2")
  elseif(CUDA_GENERATION STREQUAL "Pascal")
    set(__cuda_arch_bin "6.0 6.1")
  elseif(CUDA_GENERATION STREQUAL "Volta")
    set(__cuda_arch_bin "7.0")
  elseif(CUDA_GENERATION STREQUAL "Auto")
    execute_process( COMMAND "${CUDA_NVCC_EXECUTABLE}" ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS} "${OpenCV_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/checks/OpenCVDetectCudaArch.cu" "--run"
                     WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}${CMAKE_FILES_DIRECTORY}/CMakeTmp/"
                     RESULT_VARIABLE _nvcc_res OUTPUT_VARIABLE _nvcc_out
                     ERROR_QUIET OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)
    if(NOT _nvcc_res EQUAL 0)
      message(STATUS "Automatic detection of CUDA generation failed. Going to build for all known architectures.")
    else()
      set(__cuda_arch_bin "${_nvcc_out}")
      string(REPLACE "2.1" "2.1(2.0)" __cuda_arch_bin "${__cuda_arch_bin}")
    endif()
endif()
```

And the wikipedia CUDA page has a nice table for mapping your video card to the right microarchitecture code name (sorry, it's too large to reproduce here):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA#GPUs_supported

For example, my middling-2012 Macbook Pro has an antique GeForce GT 650M, which the wikipedia table indicates uses the Kepler microarchitecture. Therefore, I use this in my cmake command line:

`cmake -D CUDA_GENERATION="Kepler" ...`

and the opencv script converts that to "3.0 3.5 3.7" when it displays the config summary, and passes on the corresponding flags to `nvcc`.

In my case, before setting this properly, I was getting errors about `compute_70` not supported. Apparently, there is still an [open issue in the opencv tracker](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/8781) as of today (2017-10-07) about auto-detection not working properly.

Answer (score 4):

Thank you,

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D CUDA_GENERATION=Kepler ..
```

This let me install opencv-2.4.9.

If you want to know more detaills check this [link](http://vinayhacks.blogspot.com.es/2011/11/installing-opencv-231-with-ffmpeg-on-64.html).

Comment: Thank you for answering the question. This is however a link-only answer; it would be better to include a more detailed description in your answer with info from the link you're referring to.

Answer (score 3):

This is because of your gpu type is mismatching.

You have to define CUDA_GENERATION explicitly.

In my side, I could find 3 types of CUDA_GENERATION; Auto, Kepler, Fermi.

When I set CUDA_GENERATION as Kepler, compute_11 changed to compute_30 and build successful.

Answer (score 2):

You should set with `cmake` these entries `CUDA_ARCH_BIN = 3.2` and `CUDA_ARCH_PTX = 3.2`

Hope it helps.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

`cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D BUILD_TIFF=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D CUDA_GENERATION=Kepler -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON ..`

worked for me for OpenCV 2.4.11