# OpenCV fails to capture from more than 8 webcams on Linux

Tags: python, linux, opencv, limit, webcam

OpenCV fails to open VideoCaptures for more than 8 webcams on Linux.  Here a simple example:

```
# "opencap.py"
import cv2, sys
dev = int(sys.argv[1])
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(dev)
print "device %d: %s" %(dev, "success" if cap.isOpened() else "failure")
```

For my setup (OpenCV 2.4.11, Ubuntu 14.04) with, say, 9 webcams, opencap.py succeeds for the first 8 webcams (0-7), but for the last one I get

```
> python opencap.py 8
HIGHGUI ERROR: V4L: index 8 is not correct!
device 8: failure
```

Note: `v4l2-ctl --list-devices` correctly lists the 9 webcams (/dev/video0, ..., /dev/video8).

Comment: I think the GPU cannot handle the 8 webcams, especially in case the webcams have high resolution.

Comment: My application is real-time tracking of _Drosophila_.  The tracker uses _CPU_ only currently and only about 12% of an i7-4930K when tracking with 8 webcams, each at 320x240 pixels and 7.5 fps.

Comment: Then I am wrong. I will think of something else

Comment: I just checked the CPU load more carefully with `top` and `vmstat` during an experiment with 12 webcams, and got just 7% CPU (mostly user; system is about 0.4%).  This is for "experiment mode" where the tracker also displays frames and real-time heatmaps and writes M-JPEG movies.  The 12% CPU number for 8 webcams was from some ppt I wrote a few months back; glad I looked again.  :)

Comment: I don't understand a single word :D!!. Could you please simplify so that I can understand what you mean

Comment: In a nutshell, the tracker uses only 7% of an i7-4930K when tracking with 12 webcams.

Comment: @ ooh okay I got know. I read the previous comment again after the last one and I got it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is caused by this line in the OpenCV source code:

```cpp
#define MAX_CAMERAS 8
```

Simply changing the `MAX_CAMERAS` value and rebuilding OpenCV solves the problem.  The file to change is modules/highgui/src/cap_libv4l.cpp ([line 260](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/2.4.11/modules/highgui/src/cap_libv4l.cpp#L260)) for a libv4l build, and cap_v4l.cpp for a v4l build.  (See, e.g., this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36756451/1628638) for more on the two build options.)  For OpenCV 3.0, the directory changed to modules/videoio/src/.

Note: typically one runs into USB bandwidth issues with webcams before reaching the 8-camera limit.  See, e.g., this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35161718/1628638).