# Can not make a video from images using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm facing a problem here while trying to create a video from a sequence of images. This is the code:

```
video_name='resultvid10.avi'
video = cv2.VideoWriter(video_name,cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G'),1,(336,256))
for i in range(0,100):
    img = cv2.imread('./Project/data/image/video10/frame'+str(i)+'.jpg')
    result = solarPanelDetection(img)
    video.write(result)
video.release()
```

So, the video 10 has 100 frames, I extracted those frames into a folder as you can see in the code.
I passed each of every frames in this folder to a function called `solarPanelDetection`, and the output is another image called `result`, then I write this `result` to the output video. But I couldn't open the video, I check the size of the video and seems like `video.write` didn't write the `result` to the video.

I think it's not about the size of the frame and the video, the size of each frame and the video are the same, I did check carefully.

What is the problem? Can anyone help me please!

Comment: do you any resizing inside solarPanelDetection?  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46183681/opencv2-python-cv2-videowriter   and check if that bug was fixed

Comment: No, I didnt resize. I check the size of _result_ and its still the same as the video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main issues, I would like to address:

- Issue #1: Does `result` variable is a color image? since you have an initialized the `video` variable for creating a color-video.

  - `video = cv2.VideoWriter(video_name,cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G'),1,(336,256))`  is same as
  - `video = cv2.VideoWriter(video_name,cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G'),1,(336,256), isColor=True)`
  - If the `result` variable is an gray image then please initialize the `video` variable as:

    `video = cv2.VideoWriter(video_name,cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G'),1,(336,256), isColor=False)`
- Issue #2: Does `result` variable size == (336, 256, 3)?

  - You need to be sure: `assert (result.shape[0], result.shape[1]) == (336, 256)`. The statement also works, if `result` is gray-image.

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot. The problem is what you said in the Issue 1, i have to make `isColor = False`. 
About the Issue 2, the `result` shape is (336,256).

Comment: Glad, if I could help :)