# Why does the frame width / height not always get set?

Tags: python, opencv, camera, driver

There is a huge number of questions and corresponding answers of people asking how to set the frame height / width. A small sample below:

- [Unable to change frame height, width in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20387905)
- [OpenCV (via python) on Linux: Set frame width/height?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11522755)
- [Setting frame size of QuickCam Pro 3000 with OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20086967)
- [Increasing camera capture resolution in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14287)

I get it OpenCV has issues sometimes with setting frame height / width. In my case I can set a range of widths/heights up to 640 x 512. The drivers for the camera are provided by the manufacturer (i.e. not v4l2 or something similar). What debugging information can I provide or how can I help them understand why I can't set higher widths / frames. Is it a problem with the drivers, with OpenCV with both?

```
import cv2
c = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
c.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1280)
c.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 1024)
```

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and using OpenCV 2.4.8 in Python.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11420748) question which has an accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11433221) suggesting that I should be able to make it work. I don't know how to do this part:

> What you can do is to investigate your camera driver, make a patch to OpenCV and send it to code.opencv.org. This way others will enjoy your work, the same way you enjoy other's.

Answer (score 0):

You could try resizing each frame before displaying, please see code below.

Determine scaling

```py
scale_percent = 40 # percent of original size
width = int(img.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100) 
height = int(img.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100) 
dim = (width, height)
```

Apply desired scaling using the cv2.resize, before displaying.

```py
# resize output window
resized = cv2.resize(img, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA) 

#show resized frame
cv2.imshow("base_img", resized)
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: This is what I am trying.  Setting the camera parameters seems to have some effect but isn't exact.  Perhaps do to how this interacts directly with the camera, which may have a few pre-set resolutions (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420748/setting-camera-parameters-in-opencv-python).  For my needs this resize method should work.